# Hungarian Algorithm with Constrained Number of Unique Tasks

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I was wondering if there is an extension to the Hungarian algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) in which (i) A given task may be performed by more than one agent, and (ii) there is a global constraint on the total number of unique tasks being performed by the workers? For example, suppose we need a solution in which there are no more than two unique tasks being performed?

Thanks!

Comment: This question might be better on operations research stackexchange.